# boost asio multicast join

Tags: c++, boost, routes, multicast

I've made a mistake in my program using boost::asio, in that when receiving multicast data, it binds to the multicast address instead of the local interface ip.  There's no error.  Somehow on the multi-home linux host, it still received multicast data.  But when I run it on another multi-home box, it couldn't.  What did this do?

```
boost::asio::ip::address multicast_address( boost::asio::ip::address::from_string( "239.1.1.100" ) );
unsigned port( 12345 );
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket;

boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint( multicast_address, multicast_port );
socket.open( listen_endpoint.protocol() );
socket.set_option( boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address( true ) );
socket.bind( listen_endpoint );
socket.set_option( boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group( multicast_address ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `listen_endpoint` should be bound to the address of the local receiver endpoint, i.e. which network interface to use. Setting it to `any()` lets `boost` use the default receiver, e.g.:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint
    ( boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), multicast_port );
```

The `multicast_address` should just be used to join the multicast group, as per the last line.

There's some useful info about it in here: [Are you ready for IPV6?](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostcon/2011_presentations/master/wed/IPv6.pdf)

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I understood that the code has a mistake and should be the local interface of the receiver.  But what I want to know is what does 'that' block of code do now.

Comment: Sorry @surfcode I don't know, I only know that using the `multicast_address` for the `listen_endpoint` is wrong. Does it work now?

Comment: It has always been working, even with the wrong bind